# Error running a docker image, unable to locate package

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update &&
    apt-get -y install curl &&
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/akopytov/sysbench/script.deb.sh | bash

RUN apt-get -qq -y install sysbench git make gcc unzip wget lua5.1 lua5.1-dev &&
    apt-get clean

RUN wget https://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-2.4.3.tar.gz && tar zxpf luarocks-2.4.3.tar.gz && cd luarocks-2.4.3 && ./configure && make bootstrap
```

And when I try to create the image with it, at some point of the process I get this error:

```sh
Step 5/6 : RUN apt-get -qq -y install sysbench git make gcc unzip wget lua5.1 lua5.1-dev && apt-get clean
    —> Running in 4787766a3d2c
    E: Unable to locate package sysbench
    The command ‘/bin/sh -c apt-get -qq -y install sysbench git make gcc unzip wget lua5.1 lua5.1-dev && apt-get clean’ returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Anyone knows where the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer of @Erez Ben Harush has got negative point, but that link solves your issue. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reported bug about sysbench on aarch, ( which is the target arm processor that rpi uses).
Try to follow the suggestion in:
https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench/issues/298